# Почему горизонтальный скроллбар текстового поля не активен?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

Делаю виджет Text со скроллингом по X и Y.
Удивительно - по Y скроллинг отлично работает, а по X нет.
Коллеги, помогите!
Что не так?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as ttk

win = ttk.Tk()
win.title('Скроллинг текста')
win.geometry('500x200')

lbl=Label(win, width=10).grid(row=0, column=0)

scr_x=Scrollbar(win, orient=HORIZONTAL)
scr_y=Scrollbar(win, orient=VERTICAL)
txt = Text(win, width=40, height=4)

scr_x.config(command=txt.xview)
scr_y.config(command=txt.yview)

txt.config(xscrollcommand=scr_x.set)
txt.config(yscrollcommand=scr_y.set)

txt.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nswe')
scr_x.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='we')
scr_y.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='ns')

for i in range (1, 10):
    txt.insert(END, "row="+str(i)+" col= ")
    for j in range (0, 20):
        txt.insert(END, " "+str(j))
    txt.insert(END, "\n")

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну видно же, что длинные строки переносятся:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А раз за границы текстового поля по горизонтали ничего не выходит, значит и прокручивать нечего.

Чтобы работала горизонтальная прокрутка, нужно отключить перенос строк, это опция `wrap` текстового поля:

```
txt.config(wrap="none")
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уважаемый insolor, никогда бы не догадался. Благодарю.

Comment: Если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым - для этого поставьте галку слева от ответа.

Comment: Бывают же люди, которые считают, что простого спасибо всегда достаточно